# Can't seem to remove extra whitespace in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a small problem. I have some php code which gets a string stored in a database as favoritegamelist, and in the database, it doesn't appear to have any extra white space. However when I try to echo the string out it generates a bunch of new line characters. I used javascript to get the character code of the characters creating space and it was 10 and that's new line?

Either way, I figured a preg_replace function would work, or maybe trim? So I tried trim, to no avail. Currently I have this code:

```
$gamelist = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]/u', '', $row['favoritegamelist']);
echo $gamelist;
```

After this code executes, some javascript runs and collects the echo, then I log it to the console and this is where I see a ton of extra white space and I'm just stuck trying to get rid of it. The javascript code is here:

```
var mygames = document.getElementById("favoriteGamesDiv").innerHTML;
console.log(mygames);
```

favoriteGamesDiv is the area that the echo statement in php is applicable. And finally the console log that I get is:

```
        Llamas in Distress,Bow Master Halloween,Squary,
```

With all that extra space... So I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated ^-^  Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: in php just use `trim`... [Example](https://3v4l.org/kgaa7)

Comment: I tried trim, however it didn't work

Comment: Your `favoriteGamesDiv` probably has some format newlines/padding. So if you get the innerHTML, you will get all the whitespace as well.

Comment: IN javascript: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xhqke0eL/)

Comment: When i try to trim $row['favoritegamelist'] is just kinda kills everything and the log message becomes empty  Let me try javascript trim instead

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("favoriteGamesDiv").innerHTML` try `document.getElementById("favoriteGamesDiv").innerText`.

Comment: yes sadly the javascript trim also destroys the entire string.  I will try innerText

Comment: and...  I get the same results

Comment: What is the element for `favoriteGamesDiv` is that a `textarea` or `input`

Comment: try to var_dump the variable in php which helps you tou get what actually it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this it would help you..

```
$gamelist = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$row['favoritegamelist']));
```

Comment: Also you can use below for javascript : myStr = myStr.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');

Answer (score 1):

Using the `trim` of both PHP and JavaScript you can did what you want to do. Replace the `$str` with your real variable.

**PHP**

```
$str="                                Llamas in Distress,Bow Master Halloween,Squery, ";
echo trim($str);
```

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/kgaa7)

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "                                Llamas in Distress,Bow Master Halloween,Squery, ";
console.log(str.trim());
```

[Online Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xhqke0eL/)

Let me know if anything else I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem with trim or preg_replace in either language, however I ran it through a javascript function that I made to substring the values out if the charcode was from 0-31...  Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 0):

Trimming array values with trim()

```
     <?php function trim_value(&$value) 
     { 
           $value = trim($value); 
      }

  $fruit = array('apple','banana ', ' cranberry ');
 var_dump($fruit);

       array_walk($fruit, 'trim_value');
     var_dump($fruit);

   ?>
```